# python how to pass parameter from later loop back to before loop and outer loop

Tags: python, for-loop

like this loop pattern:

```py
for a in (a_start, a_end):
    for b in (b_start, b_end):
        if condition_b1:
            action_b1
        else:
            action_b2
    
    for c in (c_start，c_end):
        if condition_c1:
            action_c1
        else:
            action_c2 (pass a new a_start and b_start back)
```

as above shows, I need to pass some newly-set parameter back to before and outer loop.
How to do that?
I am waiting for answer or discussion.
I need to continue with newly-set parameters after the breakpoint.
it seems I need to pass parameters back to the very beginning.

original code as below:

```
id_number = 19
page_number_start = 4
auto_proxy_verification = 1
last_proxy_not_enough = 0

my_proxy = ['***************',
         '*****************',
         '**************',
         '**********',
         '****************',
         ]

proxy_number_start = 0
    for page_number in range(page_number_start, 999):
    login_url = f'https://***********&pageNumber={page_number}&**********'
    if proxy_number_start >= len(my_proxy): break
    for proxy_number in range(proxy_number_start, len(my_proxy)):
        try:
            driver.get(login_url)
            all_divs =       driver.find_elements_by_class_name('****classname1****')
            locked_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("****xpath1****")
            unlocked_divs =     
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("****xpath2****")
            if len(unlocked_divs) == 0:  # bad condition 1
                print('proxy not active')
                proxy_number_start = proxy_number_start + 1
            elif len(all_divs) == 10: # bad condition 2
                print('proxy not enough')
                proxy_number_start = proxy_number_start + 1
                if proxy_number_start == len(my_proxy):  ### this line is only for the last proxy
                    last_proxy_not_enough = 1
                    break
            else: # good condition
                print('proxy ok')
                proxy_number_start = proxy_number_start + 1
                break
        except:  ### if can not open the page ,means the proxy is bad
            print('proxy bad')
            proxy_number_start = proxy_number_start + 1
    main_window = driver.current_window_handle

id_number_in = 0
for div in all_divs:  ### for-loop inside the page
    if last_proxy_not_enough == 1: break
    id_number_in = id_number_in + 1
    if id_number_in < id_number:pass
    else:
        id_number = id_number + 1
        if id_number >= len(all_divs):break
        detail_body_number = 'detail-body-%d' % id_number
        first_div_class = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}"]/***/div[1]'.format(detail_body_number)).get_attribute('class')
        if first_div_class == '****certainclassname****': ## ok condition
                action = ActionChains(driver)
                action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(title_href).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                try:
                    download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('****downloadbutton*******').click()
                    print('%d is unlocked, and downloaded' % id_number)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                except:
                    try:  # if need purchase
                        purchase_button_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('****purchasebutton*******').text
                        if purchase_button_text == 'Purchase':
                            print('here purchase button!!!' % id_number)
                    except:
                        print('sometimes the proxy turns to be not active')
                        # !!!!!!!!!!!! need to pass back the parameter "page_number_start" and "id_number"
                        page_number_start = page_number_start - 1  #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!task
                        id_number = id_number_in   #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!task
                        break
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('****downloadbutton*******').click()
                    time.sleep(2)
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            print('%d is locked, pass' % id_number)
id_number = 0
```

please check how to pass back the parameters, the place I've add some !!!!!!!!! there to show my tasks.
please check how to pass back the parameters, the place I've add some !!!!!!!!! there to show my tasks.
please check how to pass back the parameters, the place I've add some !!!!!!!!! there to show my tasks.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "pass back". The loops aren't functions. Please try to give a more concrete example, showing code that doesn't do quite what you want, explaining *exactly* what it does, *exactly* what you want it to do instead, and *exactly* how that is different. Also make sure your code is indented properly. It would also help if you explained the overall purpose here. I think there is a very high probability that [you are trying to solve the wrong problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ok, i'll post my original code soon

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use while loops, like so:

```
while a <= a_end:
 while b <= b_end:
    if condition_b1:
       action_b1
    else:
       action_b2

    for c in (c_start，c_end):
       if condition_c1:
          action_c1
          a += 1
          b += 1
       else: 
          action_c2
          a = new_start
          b = new_start
```

This cycles through the values for a and b like your for-loops, but if condition c is not met, you can hop to a different value for a and b, and continue the loop from there. It's a little clunky, but I think it accomplishes what you want.

Comment: my task is more complicated, can you please check my original code? tks.

Comment: Work from here for a bit?